# Load Balancing of values into 8 "silos"

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, load-balancing

I've got a problem I can't seem to crack. It's not that easy to explain so I'll do my best :

I have a really big array of values I have already sorted :

> [ 2, 8, 26, ..., 1456, 1879, ..., 7812, 9614, ..., 20 408, 26 584 ]

I have 8 empty "silos" (kind of like an array) with unlimited capacity.

My goal is to fill those silo with all my values in order to make them as **balanced** as possible. 
When I say *"balanced"*, I mean that I want the **sum** of all the values in a silo to be *almost* equal to one another.

For example, if my silo 1 has a total sum of `52 000` and my silo 8 has a sum of `30 000` then it's not good. I'd rather have something like `41 000` and `43 500` if possible.

I've already done a round Robin, but it doesn't seem precise enough because I get a quite big difference between my silos.
I've looked up bin-packing also but it doesn't seem appropriate to me.

Thank you for any help or advice you may provide!

Comment: Suggestion: start at the back, add a number to the silo that is furthest from the highest value. Repeat.

Comment: This is a variation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem (which is NP-complete), you can look up various approximate algorithms there (in "Approximation algorithm approaches" block).

Comment: similar to this has a solution here http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-array-two-equal-sum-subarrays/ and http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/partition-a-set-into-two-subsets-such-that-the-difference-of-subset-sums-is-minimum/

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I'll check out your ideas/links right now!

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! The answer of Manfred Radlwimmer finally did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimization problems are never easy, but since you want to minimize the deviation from the average you simply iterate your values from highest to lowest value and add it to the silo with the lowest sum. That way you don't waste too much time on optimization and should (depending on your values) have a relatively good result.

```
// Generate some random data
int[] values = new int[1000];

Random r = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    values[i] = r.Next(1, 30000);
}

// Initialize silos
const int siloCount = 8;
List<int>[] result = new List<int>[siloCount];
for (int i = 0; i < siloCount; i++)
{
    result[i] = new List<int>();
}

int[] sums = new int[siloCount];
int[] indices = Enumerable.Range(0, siloCount).ToArray();

// Iterate all values in descending order
foreach (int value in values.OrderByDescending(i => i).ToList())
{
    // Find silo with lowest sum (or one of them)
    int siloIndex = indices.First(i => sums[i] == sums.Min());

    // Add to collection and sum - so we don't have to call .Sum() every iteration
    sums[siloIndex] += value;
    result[siloIndex].Add(value);
}

Debug.WriteLine(String.Join("\r\n", result.Select(s => s.Sum())));
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/4OywCC)

Comment: Wow thank you for such a fast answer! I'll try this out and keep you updated

Comment: Sir, I only have one thing to say : it's PERFECT. Exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: @Zak Glad that helped, please click the check mark at the top left of my answer to mark this answer as accepted and the question answered.